# Using the ServiceStack AuthProvider, how to limit an authenticated user to its own resources?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am using the ServiceStack Credentials AuthProvider for an REST service and the authentication process works perfect but I need to limit an authenticated user to its own resources in the database.

For example, if the user(id=1) is logged in, she can obviously retrieve her orders through /api/users/1/orders. Now, how can this user be thrown the "not authenticated" message through the /api/users/2/orders?

Comment: ever find an answer for this? I have something similar where i need to authenticate the role based on data in the request. In my case i am dealing with countries not companies and a user may have access to more than one country.

Answer (score 1):

I would not have the user Id as a route parameter, instead I would change it to `api/users/orders` or `api/orders` and then get the orders for the currently authenticated user, like so:

```
[Authenticate]
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(GetOrders request)
    {
        var userSession = base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
        var userId = int.Parse(userSession.UserAuthId);
        var dbOrders = Db.Select<Order>(x => x.UserId == userId);
        return dbOrders;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I forgot to mention this app is a multi-tenant one and the tenants are companies with their own users, orders, etc. so the CompanyId plays the main role here and I have the CompanyId in my session once a user successfully logged in. How to be more DRY? Thoughts?